# Bootstrap Avoid navbar-toggle button to close opened sub menus on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a code based on Bootstrap 3.3.7
There are different menu items and sub menus on my menu, I want to have all sub menu items to be open on mobile, Means no need to click on any menu items to display it's sub menus, So I wrote a JS code to open all sub menus on mobile:

```
function opensubmenus() {
  if ($(window).width() < 768) {
    $("#top-navbar-collapse li").addClass('open');
  } else {
    $("#top-navbar-collapse li").removeClass('open');
  }
}

$(window).resize(opensubmenus);
opensubmenus();
```

But the problem is when I click on a navbar-toggle button, It closes all submenus, But I need to keep them open on mobile devices all the time
You can check my online sample on this site: https://dedidata.com

Here I have shown a screenshot: https://pasteboard.co/IfSMCIu.jpg

I don't like to disable navbar-toggle button completely, I need it to toggle the whole navbar, But I don't like it close the submenus, My JS code opens the submenus, But navbar-toggle closes those submenus

Comment: it would be nice a minimal example of how the menu looks and what do you want to achieve...

Comment: It almost sounds like you have a "close all submenus" function being called somewhere by an attached onclick event listener. Could you provide more of your navbar code for us to see how that works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code expands the sub menus when a click occurs on `navbar-toggle`
and it change the `aria-expanded` to the correct value based on the open/close state of sub menu

```
function opensubmenus() {
    if ($(window).width() < 768) {
        $("#top-navbar-collapse li").addClass('open');
        $("#top-navbar-collapse li a").attr('aria-expanded','true');
    }else{
        $("#top-navbar-collapse li").removeClass('open');
        $("#top-navbar-collapse li a").attr('aria-expanded','false');
    }
}

$('#top-menu .navbar-toggle').click(function(){
    setTimeout(opensubmenus, 100);
});

$(window).resize(opensubmenus);
opensubmenus();
```

Thanks to @abelito for his hint

Answer (score 6):

This snippet will be applied to all dropdowns, you can modify it to get what dropdowns you need.

I will explain what it does:

```
const targets = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-toggle');

for(let i = 0; i < targets.length; i++) {
  targets[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
    targets[i].hasAttribute('data-toggle') &&
      targets[i].removeAttribute('data-toggle');

    // Managing locally the open and close
    targets[i].parentElement.classList.toggle('open');    
  });
}
```

First line:

```
const targets = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-toggle');
```

we get all the elements with class name `dropdown-toggle` (this is used in boostrap for dropdowns menus)

For each element, we attach a `click` listener to be able to manage "manually" dropdowns if the dropdown menu is clicked by the user.

This is managed by line: `targets[i].parentElement.classList.toggle('open');`

And the important one to avoid auto closing menus is to remove the attribute `data-toggle`.

```
targets[i].hasAttribute('data-toggle') &&
          targets[i].removeAttribute('data-toggle');
```

If you only one apply a solution like this for mobiles you can use [is.js](https://is.js.org/) to check when you are in mobile (android/ios)

**UPDATE**

This update will open the menus automatically:

```
const menuItems = document.getElementsByClassName('navbar-toggle');

for (let i = 0; i < menuItems.length; i++) {
  menuItems[i].hasAttribute('data-toggle') && menuItems[i].addEventListener('click', () => {    
    const elements = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-toggle');
    for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      elements[i].hasAttribute('data-toggle') && elements[i].removeAttribute('data-toggle');      
      elements[i].parentElement.classList.add('open');
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply on my problem, Your code solved my problem actually, I just wonder why my mentioned code opens those sub menus when I resize the window, But it doesn't opens those sub menus when window is lower than 768 from the start, It means it work just on resizing, Your help will be very useful, However you got the point for now too, I updated the site, It is live now

Comment: Do you want the sub menus open automatically? The solution i provided relies on user action to be able to open/close the menu and avoid overwrite that state by bootstrap. But It can be easy updated to open submenus.

Answer (score 3):

Straight code after tinkering for 10 minutes. I definitely don't recommend this as a final answer, but this will get you on the track towards one way of accomplishing it:

```
function delayedSubmenuOpen() { setTimeout(openAllSubmenus, 100); }

function openAllSubmenus() {
    var eles = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-toggle");
    for (i = 0; i < eles.length; i++) { 
        eles.item(i).parentElement.className += " open";
    }
}

var navigationHamburger = document.getElementsByClassName("navbar-toggle").item(0);
navigationHamburger.addEventListener("click", delayedSubmenuOpen);
```

I would definitely replace all of these with cross-browser compliant jQuery calls, as I did it in straight javascript and only tested in my browser on Chrome.

I'd also look into just editing the CSS instead rather than relying on javascript to do this -- maybe on page load, make a renamed copy of the ".open" class and add it to all elements with the classname "menu-item-has-children" -- this way it can't be toggled off by the javascript. Sounds like you may have tried this but definitely worth looking into rather than depending on some hokey JS.

Comment: Your code did why I need exactly, I just changed the timeout to 1, Why you put that timeout ? for visual motion ? And could you provide a code for jQuery as you recommended? I prefer to do open event on top menus only, So do you think we can do this ? Thank you so much , You got the point for now

Comment: is there a way to change inner aria-expanded="false" to true on the a tag too?

Comment: With no timeout, my computer wasn't expanding probably due to some lingering javascript from the hamburger button to auto-close it. Most phones will probably have the same issue as they don't process very fast and it could end up not expanding for them, but a 100 - 200ms delay should be plenty of time to let the javascript finish and for you to safely auto-expand. And yeah, I would just also call .setAttribute("aria-expanded", false) to whichever element makes sense

Answer (score 1):

Add this to you css

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .megamenu .dropdown ul.dropdown-menu {
        display: block;
        position: static;
        float: none;
        width: auto;
        margin-top: 0;
        background-color: transparent;
        border: 0;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        box-shadow: none;
    }
    .navbar-fixed-top .navbar-collapse {
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)!important;
    }

}
```

And change the function to look like this

```
function opensubmenus() {
  if (jQuery(window).width() < 768) {
    jQuery("#top-navbar-collapse").addClass('in');
  } else {
    jQuery("#top-navbar-collapse").removeClass('in');
  }
}

jQuery(window).resize(opensubmenus);
opensubmenus();
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply on my problem, Your code disabled navbar-toggle completely, I don't like to disable it completely, I need it to toggle the whole navbar, But I don't like it close the submenus, My JS code opens the submenus, But navbar-toggle closes those submenus, By the way I am waiting for your edit, Thank you